# ProxyPass with Cloudfare

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

For some reason I need to access https://www.upwork.com/api through reverse proxy with Apache through http://headbyte.com/api .

I created following entries in Apache config:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /api https://www.upwork.com/api
ProxyPassReverse /api https://www.upwork.com/api
```

But upwork.com is running with Cloudfare and throws DNS resolution error instead of getting the correction page as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It look like your server can't resolve the name www.upwork.com